# Can't bind mouse events to canvas layers in jCanvas/jQuery

Tags: jquery, jcanvas

I'm trying to build a tic-tac-toe game for my first foray into jQuery and jCanvas and no matter what I try, I can't figure out how to bind mouse events to the canvas layers.

This is my code: https://github.com/DanSchmidt/ttt-js/blob/master/js/script.js

I was trying to do what is being done in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/caleb531/SCNp7/5/

I've tried copying and pasting that part of the code even and it still doesn't work. I just can't see why that code should work in the fiddle and not in my own.

Comment: If I put your code inside the same jsFiddle, it seems to work for me to click box 1: http://jsfiddle.net/greglockwood/QXSrv/.

Comment: @GregL This sounds like it's worse than I thought, I have to figure out why Chrome and Firefox are not working on both my win7 and ubuntu boxes.

Comment: Are they showing any JS errors in the console? Have you included the jCanvas script properly?

Comment: @GregL I believe so because all browsers are producing the grid, and the consoles aren't showing any errors. What's stranger is that it does work in the link to your fiddle. I just tried opening a new fiddle and copying and pasting the code in yours into the new and yep it's not working. Very strange.

Comment: Finally figured it out. You were right, I was trying to include jCanvas locally and that apparently was the reason. I pointed it at the raw github and now it's working. I wonder if this is something in the browser or a file permission issue or maybe my download of jCanvas is corrupt.

Comment: Use the Resources tab in Chrome Developer tools or the Net tab in Firebug to see if it is getting the right content for the jCanvas js file when you serve it locally. It's probably best not to rely on the github raw URL as the file may be updated and break your code.

Comment: Good point, I was considering pointing it at my raw github instead of the develope's to avoid that. I'll poke around dev tools and firebug like you've suggested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jCanvas events aren't available in the stable build yet. However, they are available in the latest beta build on GitHub (v5.2b):

https://github.com/caleb531/jcanvas